# Update table from file with mysql

Tags: mysql

I am wondering whether there is a way to update the rows of a table with the updated rows stored in txt file (in a similar way as LOAD DATA INFILE works).

I know there is an update method in mysql but you have to specify the values there and I do not know how to make it read it from a file.

The txt file that I will be using contains the rows that need to be updated and I also have a list with the name of the nodes that have to be updated (only certain ones in the table). Deleting and inserting the rows in the table is not an option for me...

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Hi, what is the structure of the file and of your database?

Comment: Hi, the table I want to update is containing 300 rows with 8 columns each. the file contains a different number of rows (only the ones that we want to update) with the same 8 columns @DamianDziaduch One of the columns will be permanent (NODE ID cannot change if row is updated) and will be used to identify the row

Comment: I suggest to write a parser in any language which will put all the data in to the db :)